# Array of UIButtons, can't change button image

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uibutton

I have an array of UIButton objects (I have 15 buttons so I wanted to store them in an array for easy processing). I want to be able to iterate through the array and change the background image/image that the button uses. This is how I currently have it set up:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *greenLight;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *yellowLight;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *redLight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *task1Button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *task2Button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *task3Button;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *buttonArray;

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        [self.buttonArray addObject:self.task1Button];
        [self.buttonArray addObject:self.task2Button];
        [self.buttonArray addObject:self.task3Button];
        self.greenLight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenlight.ICO"];
        self.yellowLight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowlight.ICO"];
        self.redLight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redlight.ICO"];
        NSLog(@"init complete...");         
    }      
    return self;        
}
```

Then I have the following in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.task1Button setImage:self.redLight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [(UIButton *)self.buttonArray[1] setImage:self.greenLight forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

The second line in `viewWillAppear` works and changes the button's image. The third line, however, does not. The debugger shows the code reaching that line and not throwing any errors, so I don't know why setting the button image when the button is in an array would not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are allocating your array of buttons?

Comment: From your code sample, you are missing the allocation of your array.

self.buttonArray = [NSMutableArray new];

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing last line in your answer with this :

```
[(UIButton *)[self.buttonArray objectAtIndex:1] setImage:self.greenLight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But i'm doing this without compiler so i'm not really sure about where to place the first bracket [

Tell me if it works, i'm not totally sure about it.